# Under what circumstances on Windows can non-incremental linking result in a thrown exception, while incremental linking does not?

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild, wxwidgets

I have read that incremental linking and non-incremental linking should be functionally equivalent, but I have recently found a situation where this is not the case, and it's kind of baffling me. It that out that my project's build is unable to explicitly load one DLL (out of many) that contains a wxWidgets GUI element during runtime without incremental linking (/INCREMENTAL) enabled.

To give a little context, I have the following targets built by my project:

- main.exe
- core.dll
- foo.dll
- bar.dll

core.dll contains general functions that are used by all other projects. main.exe is a desktop GUI application (using wxWidgets) that explicitly loads foo.dll and bar.dll at runtime via "LoadLibraryW". "GetProcAddress" is then used to request GUI elements from within the DLLs to be displayed, which is all done asynchronously via wxEvent. This has worked as intended for the most part. However, I have found that an issue arises when the main.exe is not incrementally linked.

Specifically, when main.exe is not linked with a core.dll that was linked with /INCREMENTAL, and when my project is implicitly linked to the release build of wxWidgets (which is not incrementally linked), foo.dll crashes at runtime on allocation of a new wxPropertyGrid, or wxPropertyGridManager (have tried both). The exception is thrown within "wxmsw30u_propgrid_vc_x64_custom.dll", which is clearly the property grid DLL. Since the debug version of wxWidgets is incrementally linked and does not crash, I was unable to get further information than this.

**That is to say, when using the Release DLL version of wxWidgets, my project works if and only if a core.dll is linked with /INCREMENTAL and then linked into main.exe, regardless of whether or not main.exe is linked incrementally. foo.dll can be linked with a core.dll that was linked with /INCREMENTAL:NO and still be opened correctly by main.exe so long as that condition is satisfied. There are no problems with the Debug DLL version of wxWidgets, which is built with /INCREMENTAL.**

That summarizes my specific problem. Since the actual code spans several files long, I've decided to reduce this question to the fundamental problem: how could incremental linking enable what I presume to be a faulty build to run successfully? I'd like some insight into this question in particular since it is truly baffling to me.

EDIT: Specifically, I am using wxWidgets-3.0.4 on Visual Studio 2019 targeting the latest Windows 10 SDK. The machine architecture is x64. I am building the project with CMake and have experienced no such issues on Linux when linking with g++-6.3.0 and using dllopen in place of LoadLibraryW.

Comment: is everything in you project links without /INCREMENTAL? Or just those 2 pieces?

Comment: It seems that it breaks specifically when core.dll is linked non-incrementally (/INCREMENTAL:NO). If core.dll was built incrementally, then it did not matter whether or not main.exe was linked incrementally (core.dll is linked into main.exe with main.obj). foo.dll does not appear to care if it is linked incrementally.

Comment: @Igor I have clarified my language in the original post and added some bold text if it helps.